# AWS Streaming Lambda - Invoke another lambda function asynchronously

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I've been looking a this relatively [new feature of Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-response-streaming.html).

The code works well out of the box.

```
import util from 'util'; 
import stream from 'stream';
const { Readable } = stream;
const pipeline = util.promisify(stream.pipeline);

export const handler = awslambda.streamifyResponse(async (event, responseStream, _context) => {
  const requestStream = Readable.from(Buffer.from(new Array(1024*1024).join( '' )));
  await pipeline(requestStream, responseStream);
});
```

I'd like to invoke another function asynchronously and stream the payload to the other function. The function below triggers the function but the event looks like:

`event { type: 'Buffer', data: [] }`

Not sure what I'm missing to make this work.

```
import util from 'util'; 
import stream from 'stream';
const { Readable } = stream;
const pipeline = util.promisify(stream.pipeline);
import { LambdaClient, InvokeWithResponseStreamCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-lambda"; 

export const handler = awslambda.streamifyResponse(async (event, responseStream, _context) => {

const client = new LambdaClient(config);
const input = { // InvokeWithResponseStreamRequest
  FunctionName: "xxxxx", // required
  InvocationType: "Event",
  LogType: "Tail",
  Qualifier: "STRING_VALUE",
  Payload: JSON.stringify(Buffer.from(new Array(1024*1024).join( '' ))),
};
const command = new InvokeWithResponseStreamCommand(input);
const response = await client.send(command);
});
```